# What is the difference between Google Developers Console project and a Google **Play** Developers Console project?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-developer-tools

I have removed my Google Developer Console project.

Are these projects identical to each other? If I remove one, will it remove the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Difference between Google Developers Console and a Google Play Developers Console?**

**Google Developers Console:** Google Developers (previously Google Code) is Google's site for software development tools, application programming interfaces (APIs), and technical resources. The site contains documentation on using Google developer tools and APIs—including discussion groups and blogs for developers using Google's developer products.

**Google Play Developers Console:** 
Google Play or Google Play Store, and originally the Android Market, is a digital distribution platform operated by Google. It serves as the official app store for the Android operating system, allowing users to browse and download applications developed with the Android SDK and published through Google. Google Play also serves as a digital media store, offering music, magazines, books, movies, and television programs.

**Answer of your Question**

No, If you remove your project from **Developers Console** it will not delete your **Application** from **Google Play Store**, but the funcationality witch is working due to your **Google Developers Console** project stops and your Application will not work as it was previously.

**Note:** Your Project will be permanently deleted from Google Developers Console after 7 days when you deleted it. You can restore your project in the mean time.

Answer (score 3):

**The Google Developer Console** is a place where you can register your applications for using any of the Google APIs (example: Google plus) or using the Google infrastructures.

**The Google Play Developer Console** is where you upload your Android App, publish, view statistics, etc.

Removing your project from one will not remove it from the other.