# Google Developers Console and Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-console-developer, google-developer-tools

I want to implement the "sign in with Google" button in my Android app. And I read this:

> Before you can start integrating Google Sign-In in your own app, you
>   must configure a Google Developers Console project and set up your
>   Android Studio project. The steps on this page do just that. The next
>   steps then describe how to integrate Google Sign-In into your app.

And in order to publish the app I need also a Google Play Console, and I was wondering why do I need to create a Project in Google Developers Console?

Can I make this also in Google Play console??

What is the difference between Google Developers console and Google Play console?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199208/what-is-the-difference-between-google-developers-console-project-and-a-google

Comment: @AmarbirSingh tnx! one more question. Can I tranfer the Google Developer Console Project to other account?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

Comment: @AmarbirSingh thanks, but this link is regarding Google play developer console.... , is it same with Google Developers console projects?

Answer (score 1):

Google Developers console you can think of as a Google "Cloud" console. Almost anything to do with interacting with Google servers from your app is done there. Most of the APIs and features are cross-platform iOS, Android and Web. You can find it at https://console.developers.google.com/.

Signing in with Google is a cloud feature, and cross-platform so lives there. You can have a Google account on any platform.

Google Play console is focused on publishing your app to Android users. If you want stats for running your business, to affect the store listing, or roll out a new APK that's where to go.